# why do{ }while() loop doesn't work in body of a button_Click( ) method

Tags: c#, winforms

This code works correctly in a console application, but when I use it in a windows forms application it doesn't work correctly.  It never stops and it also produces no output.

I use it in a console aplication like this and it works :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter your boolean query");
        do{
            string query = Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> lst = ProcessQuery(query);
            count = 0;
            if (lst!=null)
            {
                foreach (int a in lst)
                {
                    if (a == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(documentContentList[count]);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No search result found");
            }

        }  while(1==1);

    }
```

I try to use above code on a `button_click` method in a windows forms application, but it doesn't work. I think something is wrong with `while(1==1)` - is there any equivalent?

Here is the method I wrote for the button:

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click on LoadFile Button,Please.");
            return;
        }
        if (textBox4.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter your Boolean Query");
            return;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        do{
            List<int> lst = t.ProcessQuery(textBox4.Text);
            count = 0;
            if (lst != null)
            {
                foreach (int a in lst)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(t.documentContentList[count]);
                }
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("No Search Result Found");
            }
            label1.Text = "Search = " + listBox1.Items.Count + " items, " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds + " s";
        } while (1==1);

    }
```

Comment: `while (1==1)` ????? What are you intending to do? When you do want to break out of the while loop?

Comment: This is an Infinite Loop!

Comment: @Arren, yes, it's a break point for loop but it don't work in windows form application, any replace?

Comment: @Olivia, well when do you want the `while` loop to end?

Comment: @Obama, it work like a break point in console application but when I use it in winforms it work like a Infinite Loop. I look for a replacement code.

Comment: You seriously have to ask why `while (1==1)` never stops? Delete it and never do it again. Ever.

Comment: @Arran, well, when all of my files were processed, actually it's a piece of my IR project that it able to answer any boolean query.

Comment: @Ginosaji, OK, I wanna do it but not now , first, I need an equivalent and when I found it I delete the old one, help me to find a replacing code, please.

Comment: The equivalent *is* deleting it. The code will execute every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe removing the do while loop from the button_click event handler will do the job for you.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click on LoadFile Button,Please.");
            return;
        }
        if (textBox4.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter your Boolean Query");
            return;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        //do{
            List<int> lst = t.ProcessQuery(textBox4.Text);
            count = 0;
            if (lst != null)
            {
                foreach (int a in lst)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(t.documentContentList[count]);
                }
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("No Search Result Found");
            }
            label1.Text = "Search = " + listBox1.Items.Count + " items, " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds + " s";
       // } while (1==1);

    }
```

The console application pauses execution when it waits synchronously to get user input with

```
string query = Console.ReadLine();
```

and when it gets the input it does the necessary computation and prints whatever is to be printed and waits at the same line again for the next input.

A winform application does not work this way, it already has an event loop that processes UI activity (KeyPressed etc.)

In short, you do not need a loop in the handler method.

Comment: Then you need to look into the implementation of your `ProcessQuery` method. It's returning `null` every time.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms or WPF, the UI is managed by only a single thread.  So if you have an endless loop inside the code that the UI is calling from its thread, it will block forever, and be unable to continue updating the UI.  This is why you won't see any dialog boxes appear.

Instead, you should run something like this code in its own Thread, or probably more easily within the construct of a BackgroundWorker object (and then using the DoWork and ProgressChanged events).

Answer (score 0):

In your Console example, the `Consol.ReadLine()` call blocks the UI & waits for input. By using the infinite while loop, you effectively allow users to enter as many queries as they want. However, in a Forms/WPF based application an infinite loop is actually a terrible idea, plus the application will stay up until closed, rather than closing immediately upon completion of your work (which is why you use the infinite loop in a Console application).

This is because Forms based applications leverage a dedicated thread to update the UI. By blocking this thread you also prevent any other UI updates from occurring, freezing up your application. Based on what you're trying to do, the `button6_Click` event method should offload this work to a BackgroundWorker ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx)), which allows work to be performed on another thread then marshalled updates onto the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear to me; in your console application you have a Console.ReadLine inside the loop which makes it to stop until the user enters a value and hit Return. In the form application you don't need the do while loop. The users enter a value in the textBox4 and click a button to process the request.

Comment: yeah, I got it. thanks for answering me. and solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

In a console application, `Main` is the *entry point* for the application. All programs have this function and it is called by the operating system when you launch an executable.

Once called, it will be executed like any other function would (from top to bottom) and if `Main` returns a value it does so to the OS and the OS terminates the program.

To keep the program from exiting after one run it is common practice to use a `while` loop to make sure that the end of the `main` function isn't reached (and a `return` executed).

`Console.ReadLine` is a **blocking** function - this means that it will not let the next line of code to execute until it has finished doing whatever it does (in this care, read input from the user).

So your console application runs line by line until it gets input. Then it evaluates this, outputs a string and repeats forever.

Now, in a WinForms application things are managed a little differently. The UI (buttons, form, text boxes etc) is handled by the main thread, which means that you need to give it time to update. By having an endless loop within your button click function you are never returning control to the main thread and the UI locks up.

If you just want the function to run multiple times, remove the `while` loop and the code will run every time the button is clicked. Winforms will handle that for you.

If it still locks the UI, the code is blocking for too long (within the button event).

If so, you have to do intensive work either asynchronously (bit by bit) or offload the work to another thread. Look into using [backgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to ensure the UI doesn't freeze up, and remove the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have infinite loop condition in both examples - so your program is never able to gracefully exit the loop, even in your console application you probably exit by closing the console form by clicking on it's 'x', that is wrong.. a program should have a logic implemented to allow the user to exit from it gracefully.
2. The reason that your 2nd example don't work as you expect it to is because it is never allowed to refresh your user interface. it is a bad practice to put infinite loops however to prove to you that it is actually not stuck or freezes and it just unable to refresh the user interface add another command in your loop as follows:

```
   :
        listBox1.Items.Add("No Search Result Found");
        }
        label1.Text = "Search = " + listBox1.Items.Count + " items, " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds + " s";
       Application.DoEvents(); // add that line
    } while (1==1);
```

the `Application.DoEvents();` halt the execution of your loop and allows the graphic user interface thread to update the window.

But as I stated earlier - this is not the correct way to develop an application, a better way would be to simply remove that loop, as follows:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click on LoadFile Button,Please.");
            return;
        }
        if (textBox4.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter your Boolean Query");
            return;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

        List lst = t.ProcessQuery(textBox4.Text);
        count = 0;
        if (lst != null)
        {
            foreach (int a in lst)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(t.documentContentList[count]);
            }
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("No Search Result Found");
        }
        label1.Text = "Search = " + listBox1.Items.Count + " items, " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds + " s";
    }
```

Now, each time you click the button it will invoke your event handler and as the event handler exit the routine the user interface will automatically be updated. since your form is derived from the System.Windows.Form class the instructions to keep the windows message pump going until the user click 'x' is already implemented for you in the parent class, that is the System.Windows.Form class your form is deriving from.

Of course, that in console application this will not be the case.